# Handle traffic in 2D city builder

Tags: 2d, simulation, traffic, isometric

I´m creating a 2D isometric city building simulation and today I have kind of a "best practice" question without asking for specific code.
As in all city building games you are able to place building, roads and so on. The player is able to place building everywhere, no matter if it´s connected to a road or not. In addition to that there is one building (call it center building) all the buildings need to be connected with (by road). 
I need to handle that without doing too many calculations which, breaks the FPS.

Right now I have a timer job for each building which checks if one of the surrounded tiles of a building is a road. That works fine, also for a lot of buildings since the check is simple. 
But now I would like to check the connection to the center building. To check that it is necessary (in my opinion) to use something like a pathfinder, which checks if one of the surrounded tiles has a road connection to one of the surrounded tiles of the center building. 
I can not check that frequently because this completely smashes the FPS down to 30 or lower. My idea was to fire an event if a road has been built or destroyed to "recalulate" the road connection. But there comes another problem...the player might destoy a road in the middle of the map and the buildings are really far away from each other so I need to find the involved buildings which also might take too much time.

My last idea is creating something like a timer queue and work through these items gradually, but before I keep using the trial and error method I would like to ask you for ideas.

Really looking forward to your ideas!
Yheeky

Answer (score 0):

You could have each building store a list of tiles (a path) that connects it to the center building. Then when a tile is randomly destroyed by the player, you can have each building tested to see if it pathed through that road tile or not.

Alternatively you could have each road tile store which buildings require it, so when the tile is destroyed you have the buildings immediately throw flags. This could get quite messy though, but lends itself decently to background speed cleanup calls.

Both methods are quite messy. Perhaps you can make it a rule that the player can't place roads except next to other roads or next to the center building. Then when the player deletes a road tile, do a paint-style fill that destroys all of the disconnected roads. You can also periodically do a random check on tiles to see if they are illegally placed or not, but that should be unnecessary if you're careful.